# Pass Docker argument environment to deploy in k8s using helm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes-helm

I need a information , i am trying all day with no help , any help is much appreciated .

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20181114
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless 

# Add jar file to container. JAR_FILE also provided as argument
ARG JAR_FILE='**/*.jar'
ADD ${JAR_FILE} document_service.jar
RUN echo -e ' \n export DATABASENAME=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/nldwh/databasename --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $DATABASENAME'  >> /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e ' \n export DATABASEUSER=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/nldwh/username --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $DATABASEUSER'  >> /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e ' \n export  AWSBUCKETNAME=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/awss3/bucketname --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $AWSBUCKETNAME'  >> /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e ' \n export  AWSACCESSKEY=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/awss3/accesskey --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $AWSACCESSKEY'  >> /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e ' \n export  AWSSECRETKEY=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/awss3/secretkey --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $AWSSECRETKEY'  >> /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN echo -e ' \n export DATABASEPASS=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/nldwh/password --query SecretString --output text` \n echo $DATABASEPASS \n cd \n java -jar /document_service.jar' >> /opt/entrypoint.sh

ARG env_name

# Run the generated shell script.
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is my values.yml file

```
replicaCount: 1

#pass repository and targetPort values during runtime
image:
  repository: 
  tag: "latest"
  pullPolicy: Always
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80
  targetPort: 
  
profile: "aws" 
cmd:
   ArgA: dev
```

This is my deployment.yml file

````
spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          #args: [
          #"--ArgA={{ .Values.cmd.ArgA }}" ]```
````

my helm install command is

helm upgrade --install  $(servicename) -f values_dev.yaml

My docker build file

```
- download: 'current' 
    
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/../drop
      ls -lrt 
      ls -lrt target
      pwd
      echo $MYATHLONTRUST
      docker build --no-cache --pull -t ${{ parameters.servicename }}:latest .
      docker image ls | head -2
  displayName: 'Building Docker Image'

error message and output:

/usr/bin/bash /var/build/Ubuntu0205/_work/_temp/ebf1fa80-e5c1-4b35-9368-75166c468b69.sh
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 3 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 4096 Mar 10 11:19 $HOME
drwxr-xr-x 4 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 4096 Mar 10 11:19 src
drwxr-xr-x 7 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 4096 Mar 10 11:19 target
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 5864 Mar 10 11:55 azure-pipelines.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent  248 Mar 10 11:55 Dockerfile.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent  440 Mar 10 11:55 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 1072 Mar 10 11:55 entrypoint.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 9547 Mar 10 11:55 pom.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent  915 Mar 10 11:55 README.md
total 149932
drwxr-xr-x 2 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent      4096 Mar 10 11:19 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x 3 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent      4096 Mar 10 11:19 sonar
drwxr-xr-x 3 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent      4096 Mar 10 11:19 maven-status
drwxr-xr-x 3 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent      4096 Mar 10 11:19 classes
drwxr-xr-x 3 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent      4096 Mar 10 11:19 generated-sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent     90036 Mar 10 11:55 myathlon-restapi-document-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
-rw-r--r-- 1 srv-vstsagent srv-vstsagent 153417052 Mar 10 11:56 myathlon-restapi-document-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
/var/build/Ubuntu0205/_work/34/drop

Dependency Updated:
  elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.176-2.amzn2  libblkid.x86_64 0:2.30.2-2.amzn2.0.5 
  libmount.x86_64 0:2.30.2-2.amzn2.0.5    libuuid.x86_64 0:2.30.2-2.amzn2.0.5  

Complete!
Error removing intermediate container 46b80034bc4a: No such container: 46b80034bc4ae08bc76c6c75bc081f051c1a0a0494d63c4ec2e1c9cff6ba39cb
 ---> 68085751f7cd
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app                           # avoid / container root directory
 ---> Running in 8b75df62cfcf
Error removing intermediate container 46b80034bc4a: No such container: 46b80034bc4ae08bc76c6c75bc081f051c1a0a0494d63c4ec2e1c9cff6ba39cb
 ---> 536ee4f4ebf6
Step 4/8 : ARG JAR_FILE='**/*.jar'
 ---> Running in de5054ea9f5b
Error removing intermediate container 46b80034bc4a: No such container: 46b80034bc4ae08bc76c6c75bc081f051c1a0a0494d63c4ec2e1c9cff6ba39cb
 ---> 8e206092f7c9
Step 5/8 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} document_service.jar  # prefer COPY to ADD
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat document_service.jar: file does not exist
REPOSITORY                                                                        TAG                                                                       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
<none>                                                                            <none>                                                                    8e206092f7c9   2 minutes ago       660MB
Finishing: Building Docker Image
```

what i am trying to achieve is during the deployment , the docker file variable env_name should be replaced with the environment dev or test or acc .(this should happen during the docker deployment stage not in the build stage because i am planning to use the same image for dev and test).

so for test if i deploy the same image which i build for dev then when deploying , it should fetch the aws secrets for test and not dev

I tried all i can but cant figure out , the $1 is not getting replaced with dev value .

Any help is really really appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have included image files in your question in place of the Dockerfile and relevant YAML files.  Can you [edit] the question to replace those images with the actual text?  That will be much easier to read and potentially reproduce.

Comment: A Dockerfile is built and pushed to a registry before anything in Kubernetes happens; nothing you'd set in a Kubernetes YAML file can change what happens in a Dockerfile.  You could run the same image in multiple Deployments with different environment variable settings or commands and it wouldn't get rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply , what i am trying here is i have a docker file , after the docker build , i am planning to deploy the same image to dev/test , when i deploy in dev it should get the dev password and when i deploy the same image to test it should get the test password and bring up the application , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to set environment variables in a Dockerfile.  [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) values are only visible in `RUN` instructions, and can't be changed after the image has been built.  [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) values are visible while the container is running to (in the `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD`) and can be changed when the container is run, but can't be directly set at build time.

Since this is a value you're trying to set when the container is running, you want `ENV` and not `ARG`.  In your Kubernetes manifest, you can change this using a Pod spec's [`env:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#environment-variables) setting.  (Also Compose [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) or the `docker run -e` option.)

More specifically in a Helm context, I would recommend making "environment name" a configurable value, rather than pass in an undifferentiated list of command-line arguments or environment values.

```yaml
# values.yaml

# environmentName specifies the environment name used to look up
# secrets in AWS Secrets Manager.
environmentName: dev
```

Then in the Pod spec embedded inside the Deployment spec, add this in an `env:` block.

```yaml
# charts/myathlon/templates/deployment.yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          env:
            - name: env_name
              value: {{ .Values.environmentName }}
```

As a cleanup I'd also recommend breaking out the entrypoint script into its own script file, rather than trying to build it a line at a time in the Dockerfile.  This will be easier to read and maintain.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Check: $env_name must be set
if [ -z "$env_name" ]; then
  echo '$env_name is not set; stopping' >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Retrieve secrets from Secrets Manager
export DATABASENAME=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/nldwh/databasename --query SecretString --output text`
...
export DATABASEPASS=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myathlon/$env_name/nldwh/password --query SecretString --output text`

# Run the main container CMD
exec "$@"
```

Since you don't have a default value for `$env_name`, you don't particularly need to declare anything in the Dockerfile.  I included a check at the top of the extracted entrypoint wrapper script that will exit if its unset at container startup time.  That reduces the Dockerfile to:

```sh
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20181114
RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless 
WORKDIR /app                           # avoid / container root directory
ARG JAR_FILE='**/*.jar'
COPY ${JAR_FILE} document_service.jar  # prefer COPY to ADD
COPY entrypoint.sh .                   # also COPY in entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]      # split ENTRYPOINT wrapper from
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/document_service.jar"] # main CMD
```

Comment: Many thanks David for the really  long information , awesome , i have some error in my build docker file because of location of the Dockerfile and my jar file , i edited the information in the question , is that something wrong their David ??

Comment: my Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh is present in  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/../drop but the document-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is present in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/../drop/target directory and my build command is  docker build --no-cache --pull -t ${{ parameters.servicename }}:latest .

Comment: If the jar file is outside the `docker build` context directory (the `.` argument at the end) you can't include it in the image.  I copied the Dockerfile fragment from the question, but Docker doesn't understand extended glob syntax like `**` for "in any subdirectory".  Maybe `ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar` would work better?  Asking a new question would be a little clearer than adding a second problem to your existing question.

Comment: Hi David , i think it is almost ok but still checking but want to let u know , super .. thanks david it saved my life , cheers

Comment: after bit of modification, it worked great David , thanks